# calculate center item in array vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm currently busy creating a custom vue carousel component. I have been using some parts of the code from here: [link](https://medium.com/@davidatomhernandez/how-to-a-simple-carousel-with-vue-138715d615d7)

At this moment I want to be able to make the slider have an extra feature which should be little navigation bullets. For this I need to know the active slide which is visible. Because of the justify-content:center it always shows the middle item in my array.

I currently want to calculate the active item by defining the middle item in my array. I try to do this as follows:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                slides: [
                {
                  title: 'I am slide A',
                  featured: 1,
                  img: '/images/carousel-img.png',
                  id: 1
                },
                {
                  title: 'I am Slide B',
                  featured: 0,
                  img: '/images/carousel-img.png',
                  id: 2
                },
                {
                  title: 'I am Slide C',
                  featured: 0,
                  img: '/images/carousel-img.png',
                  id: 3
                }
            ],
            activeImage: (this.slides.length / 2)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This doesn't of course work, but i have no clue on how to go from here. Anybody here could give me a push in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: could you try `Math.floor(this.slides.length / 2)` to get the index of the middle of the array?

Comment: Sadly I get the error of 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'. Am I doing something wrong here which I oversee?

Comment: It's because you cannot reference property of the same object literal using `this` keyword. Check the example in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slides.length / 2` - will return `float` value for array with odd number of items.
So try

```
Math.floor(slides.length / 2)`
```

or

```
~~(slides.length / 2)
```

to get the integer value

Then you can use this index to access the item in the array

```
slides[Math.floor(slides.length / 2)]
```

Example:

```
const demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',

  data: {
      slides: [
        {
          title: 'I am slide A',
          featured: 1,
          img: '/images/carousel-img.png',
          id: 1
        },
        {
          title: 'I am Slide B',
          featured: 0,
          img: '/images/carousel-img.png',
          id: 2
        },
        {
          title: 'I am Slide C',
          featured: 0,
          img: '/images/carousel-img.png',
          id: 3
        }
      ],
  },

  methods: {

    getActiveImage: function () {
        return Math.floor(this.$data.slides.length / 2);
    }

  }
});

// In template: <div> {{getActiveImage()}} </div>
```